# What affects the colour of the Startup Screen?

Tags: macos, startup

I've seen Macs startup with a white [very pale grey] screen & some with a black screen.

<sub>*random pics from interweb...*</sub>

[image] [image]

What differentiates which it will be?

My own machines here - 2 old Mac Pros, 3,1 & 5,1 are always white [grey] & have never started up with the black background.

Comment: I'm inclined to say: left Parallels & right VMware (considering the "high quality" of the "screenshots" - no flashlight, no office lamps, no mirrored faces, )

Comment: LOL @klanomath. I just pulled thumbs from google as an indicator [quality/source/legitimacy wasn't on my agenda]  ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's based on the [board ID in boot.efi](https://github.com/w0lfschild/DarkBoot/blob/06423c93008822188ab010b4a547a35722393c3c/DarkBoot.command#L67-L79). Depending on the model of computer, a black boot screen will be shown (introduced with Yosemite) instead of the older grey screen.

All these Macs and newer show the black boot screen:

- MacBookPro10,1 (Retina, Mid 2012)
- MacBookAir6,1 (Mid 2013)
- iMac14,1 (Late 2013)
- MacPro6,1 (Mid 2012)

Here's boot.efi from macOS 10.13.2 with the board IDs highlighted beside the string "Background Color".

[image]

You may be able to use [**Dark Boot**](https://w0lfschild.github.io/app_dBoot.html) to patch your boot.efi's board ID so the dark boot screen is displayed.

Comment: Clicking download on the linked page gives version 4.0.5, latest release on github is [**5.2.0**](https://github.com/w0lfschild/app_updates/tree/master/DarkBoot).